# Почему не работает apply для некоторых столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas

Мой фрейм данных "до того":

[image: Df_row]

```
df_row.apply(lambda x: x.replace('\t', ''), axis=1),
```

Но `apply` применяется  не ко всем столбцам:

[image: Df_row после]

А так работает:

```
'\tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)'.replace('\t', '')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, никогда не публикуйте данные картинками, их нельзя скопировать, чтобы просто вставить во фрейм данных. По возможности, замените на текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), но только для строковых столбцов.

Рабочий пример:

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Formula":['\tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)'] * 3, "level_number": [1,2,3]})

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
                   Formula  level_number
0  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             1
1  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             2
2  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             3

In [11]: str_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq("object")]

In [12]: df.loc[:, str_cols] = df.loc[:, str_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("\t", ""))

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                 Formula  level_number
0  Formula A: UNIQUES(A)             1
1  Formula A: UNIQUES(A)             2
2  Formula A: UNIQUES(A)             3
```

**NOTE:** постарайтесь в будущем приводить в вопросах [воспроизводимые примеры данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/).